# Is it legal for a 19 year old or a 20-21 year old to view internet porn?

Tags: internet, pornography

I'm curious to know is it legal for a 19 year old or a 20-21 year old to view internet porn, is it legal or otherwise?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: I'm just asking if it's legal for a 19-21 year old to view online porn.

Comment: And I’m just saying that the answer depends on the laws where you live.  So, where do you live?

Comment: I'm from New York.

Comment: @AmberAlvia, this is law.stackexchange.com. You were not asked where you are from, because that is totally irrelevant. You were asked where you live.

Comment: From…. Live…. These terms are commonly used interchangeably.  And as Jen pointed out, where the OP lives is also totally irrelevant.  “Is there a particular jurisdiction you are interested in?” Would have been a better question.  Sorry to get you all worked up.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally legal for any person to view non-obscene porn, though there may be jurisdictions where all porn is deemed to be obscene. In the majority of jurisdictions, it is not forbidden for a person to view porn, but there may be restrictions in some jurisdictions (i.e. most) as to who a purveyor may show or direct porn to, but there the limit is on showing, not viewing. In order to protect themselves from legal action, a porn-purveyor may seek to limit access to those who are "old enough", via a conditional agreement (you may view, if you swear that you are old enough, plus possibly other conditions). It would not be legal to break that promise (lie about your age), but the illegality comes in violating the contract and not in viewing the porn.

In most jurisdictions the [age of majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority) is 18, but bear in mind that the concept can be purpose-specific (driving, contracting, drinking). It might be illegal in the UAE, but not in Washington.

Comment: You mean it's generally legal for anyone over 18 to view non-obscene porn, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In many places, [viewing internet porn is illegal at any age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_laws_by_region).  A quick internet search reveals that in places that try to restrict young people's exposure to pornography, it's typically illegal to show pornography to a person below a certain age, but watching it is not an offense for the young person.

The age threshold is frequently 18, but I did not find a list of age limits in different jurisdictions.  So the answer is probably "in places where the legality depends on the viewer's age, anyone who is 18 or older is not restricted," but there may be jurisdictions that have a higher (or lower) threshold.  (And don't forget that any offences connected with the viewing are committed by people other than the viewer, not by the viewer.)

Thus, for jurisdictions that don't prohibit pornography altogether, the answer to the question

> is it legal for a 19 year old or a 20-21 year old to view internet porn?

...is that in most such jurisdictions it is probably legal.

Answer (score 0):

Many countries ban the *possession* of certain forms of pornography, notably involving underage participants and sometimes violence and humiliation.

When it comes to viewing something *on the internet,* the media actually gets downloaded to the local machine and displayed there. Technically it is different from going to a DVD rental shop and getting a physical disk, but legally the viewer will be "in possession" of the material when it is on the local computer. There are also specific laws regarding porn on the internet in some countries, but basically the laws are no different from having a printed magazine stashed in a drawer.